# "dotted field names are only allowed at the top level" when doing $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

I am doing an `aggregation` with a `project` with a `cond`. Something like this...

Assume Document of:

```
{outter:{
    inner1:"blah",
    innerOther:"somethingelse"
}}
```

Aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
   $project : {
       "outter.inner1":1,
       "outter.inner2":{
          $cond : if:{"outter.innerOther":{$exists:true}},
                  then:{"blah":"blah"},
                  else:{"blah":"blah"}
       }
   }
}])
```

When I run this I get an error: `exception: dotted field names are only allowed at the top level` on the `if` condition statement (I tried replacing the if with `if:true` and the aggregation works).

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround without doing a whole other project to simply get the field available without a dot?

**EDIT**

So I found a workaround but would still like to see if this is expected behavior. The workaround is to use a variable in the projection via `$let`. Also, it appears that `$exists` is not a valid `expression` so had to also make the following change.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
   $project : {
       "outter.inner1":1,
       "outter.inner2":{
          $let :{
              vars:{innerOther:{$ifNull:["$outter.innerOther", "absent"]}},
          }
          $cond : if:{$eq:["$$innerOther","absent"]},
                  then:{"blah":"blah"},
                  else:{"blah":"blah"}
       }
   }
}])
```

Comment: Is "outter" an array? please can you show your documents?

Comment: Outter is a sub-document.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can't use the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) because it's only valid in expression with the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator or within the [`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method. That being said you can use the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) in the `if` condition but you need to [prefix it with the `$` sign](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables) which is missing in your first query. Also you can't return a literal object key/value pairs as value of  or  expression because it is not a valid [aggregation  expressions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) you need to use the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) instead.

Now one way to do this as you mention is using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operation and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)ion. Of course the `$ifNull` conditional operator returns the present value of the field if it exists or the replacement expression.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "outter.inner1": 1,
        "outter.inner2.blah": { 
            $let: { 
                vars: { 
                    "outterinner2": { 
                        $ifNull: [ "$outter.innerOther", "absent" ]
                    }
                }, 
                in: { 
                    $cond: [ 
                        { $eq: [ "$$outterinner2", "absent" ] }, 
                        "blah", 
                        "blah"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Another way of doing this is using two [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)ion stages.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "inner1": "$outter.inner1", 
        "inner2": {
            $ifNull: [ "$outter.innerOther", "absent" ] 
        }
    }}, 
    { $project: { 
        "outter.inner1": "$inner1", 
        "outter.inner2.blah": { 
            $cond: [ 
                { $eq: ["$inner2", "absent"] }, 
                "blah", 
                "blah" 
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Both queries yield something like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5632713c8b13e9fb9cc474f2"),
        "outter" : {
                "inner1" : "blah",
                "inner2" : {
                        "blah" : "blah"
                }
        }
}
```

EDIT:

"dot notation" is allowed in the `$cond` operator. For example the following query use the "dot notation".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "outter.inner1": 1, 
        "outter.inner2.blah": { 
            $cond: [ 
                { $eq: [ "$outter.innerOther", "somethingelse" ] }, 
                "anotherThing", 
                "nothing" 
            ] 
        } 
    }}
])
```

and yields:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56379b020d97b83cd1506650"),
    "outter" : {
            "inner1" : "blah",
            "inner2" : {
                    "blah" : "anotherThing"
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm.... and by this:

```
Model.aggregate([
                    {
                        $project: {
                            name: 1,
                            "indexes.name":{
                                $cond: {
                                    if: {$eq:["$indexes.name",'стафилококки']},
                                    then: "$indexes.name",
                                    else: null
                                }
                            },
                            "indexes.units":1
                        }
                    }
                ], callback)
```

**always return "null" for name.indexes**

```
[ 
   { _id: 564c6a5991b08dd017c2bd23,
     name: ' воздух ',
     indexes: [ [Object] ] },
   { _id: 564c6cf091b08dd017c2bd24,
     name: 'repa ',
     indexes: [ [Object] ] },
]
```

where indexes are:

```
[ { units: 'fvf', name: null } ]
[ { units: 'КОЕ', name: null } ]
```

Comment: I have studied my case above. Its unbelievable,** but "$indexes.name" in $cond transformed in array ["стафилококки"] !?  Although in reality it is a string like "units"!**                                      So.. there is no equality (["стафилококки"] !="стафилококки"), and $cond always return false, e.g. null